# scheiden oder trennen?

Tags: verb-usage

Wie würdet ihr den entscheidenden Unterschied zwischen **scheiden** und **trennen** erklären? Sie sind Synonyme, ich weiß das, aber gibt es Regeln (oder sowas) dazu, wenn und in welchen Kontexten, Phrasen, usw. man sie benutzen darf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beide Verben haben zwei Bedeutungen:

1. im physikalischen oder chemischen Sinne, wenn es um Substanzen geht
2. im übertragenen Sinne, wenn es um Beziehungen zwischen zwei Menschen geht.

Bei 1) ist *scheiden* eher veraltet, wird aber wohl insbesondere bei Metallen noch verwendet. Der Einleitungssatz in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edelmetallscheidung lautet passenderweise

> Edelmetall**scheidung** (englisch Precious Metals Refining) ist ein übergeordneter Begriff zur **Trennung** von edelmetallhaltigen Rohstoffe[n].

(Hervorhebung von mir). Ansonsten sehe ich keinen Bedeutungsunterschied.

Bei 2) wird *sich scheiden* (oder auch *sich scheiden lassen*, da die Scheidung vom Gericht vorgenommen wird) auf Ehebeziehungen angewandt, während *sich trennen* auf partnerschaftliche Beziehungen angewandt wird, die keine Ehen sind.

Comment: Bei Metallen ist "scheiden" immer noch sehr gebräuchlich -> ***Degussa***

Comment: **De**utsche **G**old **u**nd **S**ilber-***S**cheide*anstalt. In dem Firmennamen steckt das *Scheiden*, das vor allem bei Edelmetallen und im Hüttenwesen durchaus verwendet wird und deswegen keinesfalls veraltet ist, drin

Comment: @tofro: Danke für den Hinweis, hab meinen Beitrag entsprechend editiert.

Comment: Auch in einer Ehe kann man sich trennen. Man lebt dann nicht mehr zusammen, ist (auf dem Papier) aber noch verheiratet. Diese Trennung ist sogar Voraussetzung für eine [Scheidung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehescheidung_(Deutschland)).

Comment: @Raketenolli Genau, die Ehebeziehung ist dann noch nicht geschieden, die partnerschaftliche Beziehung ist aber getrennt. Das harmoniert doch mit dem, was ich geschrieben habe.

Answer (score 0):

*Trennen* betont den vorherigen (ungetrennten) Zustand, wie bei *Eier trennen*, während bei *Scheiden* offenbar das Ergebnis der Trennung im Vordergrund steht.

Beim Edelmetall erkennt man das besonders gut, weil man dadurch wieder zu reinem Silber kommt.

> Gott schied das Licht von der Finsternis
>
> die Schafe von den Böcken scheiden